# Nodejs acepts only a couple of requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express

I'm using j query to send requests to a local server. After sending between 4-7 requests the port stops working and doesn't return an error. After a couple of minutes some of the request are sent to the local web server, while the others  return an error. The request format is a name to a file. After that the server checks the last time the file was edited every 10 seconds.

> net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

or

> net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

I searched on stack overflow for answers i found this [Heroku app stops responding after a couple of requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20425063/heroku-app-stops-responding-after-a-couple-of-requests) leading to [http agent](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_agent)
I saw that it uses http and I'm using express so i think it wouldn't work. I think it may work with different ports but since it doesn't return an error instantly i don't know how to know to change to a different port.

HTML(the post request to the local server)

```
$.post("http://localhost:6458"+String(tickup)+"/",{"":file})
```

Express server

```js
function logEvery(i,path) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        fs.stat(path, (err, stats) => {
            console.log(stats.mtimeMs)
        })
        logEvery(i,path);
    }, i)
}

router.post('/',(request,response) => {
    //code to perform particular action.
    //To access POST variable use req.body()methods.
    console.log(request.body["[0][]"]);
    console.log(request.body["[1][]"]);
    logEvery(timer, request.body["[0][]"]);
});
```

Comment: You should at least send empty response.

Comment: ex; `res.send('success')` after the very last line in `router.post('/', ...`

Comment: ok thanks and will the solution with the use of many ports work

Comment: thanks it fixed the whole problem

Answer (score 0):

You missed sending a response. That's why your request is Time-outed.

```js
function logEvery(i,path) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        fs.stat(path, (err, stats) => {
            console.log(stats.mtimeMs)
        })
        logEvery(i,path);
    }, i)
}

router.post('/',(request,response) => {
    //code to perform particular action.
    //To access POST variable use req.body()methods.
    console.log(request.body["[0][]"]);
    console.log(request.body["[1][]"]);
    logEvery(timer, request.body["[0][]"]);
    response.send('started');           // <-- newly added
});
```

Comment: @dimo-jordanov Please accept the answer if it is correct so that others can refer to this in the future.